# Bootstrap-Vue b-dropdown button color when open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

The code below gets me what I need in terms of button color and hover. However, the button color goes back to the default gray when the menu is open and you move your cursor away from the button. How can you customize the button when the menu is open?

Current code that works:

```
<style scoped>
    /deep/ .dropdown > button {
        color:#001E61;
        background:#ffffff;
        border-color:#001E61;
        font-weight:bold;

    }
    /deep/ .dropdown > button:hover {
        color:#E81F76;
        background:#ffffff;
        border-color:#E81F76;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
```

Code I have tried to customize color of the button when menu is open:

```
<style scoped>
    /deep/ .dropdown > button:hover,
    .dropdown > button:active,
    .dropdown > button:focus    {
        color:#E81F76;
        background:#ffffff;
        border-color:#E81F76;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</scoped>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the dropdown is expanded, the `.dropdown` div has a `.show` class applied, which you can use to style the button:

```css
/deep/ .dropdown.show > button {
  background: red;
}
```

Also if your project is current, it's recommended to use `>>>` rather than `/deep/`, which is deprecated.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. Quick question, is there a source that has all these classes for each bootstrap component?

Comment: You're welcome.  There isn't one that I know of.  This class is mentioned in the normal Bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) but I inspected to find it